# Populate cells based on x by y cell value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function, modular-arithmetic

I'm trying to populate cells based on values from two different cells. 
Values in the cell needs to be (n-1) where n is the input and then repeated based on the amount of the other cell.

For example, I have input:

```
x     y  
2     5
```

Output should be:

- x should have `0` and `1`; each repeated five times
- y should have `0`, `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`; each repeated twice

```
x1   y1  
0    0  
0    1  
0    2  
0    3  
0    4  
1    0  
1    1  
1    2  
1    3  
1    4
```

I used:

```
=IF(ROW()<=C2+1,K2-1,"")
```

and

```
=IF(ROW()<=d2+1,K2-1,"")
```

but it is not repeating and I only see:

```
  
x   y  
0   0  
1   1  
__  2  
__  3  
__  4
```

(C2 and D2 are where values for x and y are, K is the number of items.)

Are there any suggestions on how I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Row2 and copied down to suit:

```
=IF(ROW()<=1+C$2*D$2,INT((ROW()-2)/D$2),"")
```

and

```
=IF(ROW()<=1+C$2*D$2,MOD(ROW()-2,D$2),"")
```

Comment: What if I have a third column for z?